# Magento2.2.5 make root.phtml load from child theme folder

Tags: magento-2.2.5, parent-child-theme

I am developing a custom "child" theme based off Luma and wondering how I might add a custom root.phtml .
I have copied the entire contents of the vendor/theme-frontend-luma to my
app/design/frontend/ folder now I also in the app/design/frontend/ have a child theme folder created. My issue is no matter what it always seems to load the root.phtml from the app/design/frontend/ folder and not the app/design/frontend// when I am viewing the child theme.

Does Magento2 not allow the root.phtml to be loaded from a child theme?I am trying to add additional links to css, and js files that are unique per store view/child them because this is a multi-site that uses different child themes for different store views.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
Please follow step.

1) create custom root.phtml in this folder.
`app/design/frontend/child_theme/Magento_Theme/templates/root.phtml`

2) clear cache: `bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Thanks xanka , However it does not work for me and maybe its because I am trying to do it in a child theme folder ? My folder structure is app/design/frontend/design/Kiss/luma_kiss . 

I am using Luma as the parent and the only custom thing I am trying to do is add a custom css and some js files to the child theme folder. Your above way only works if I edit the root in the vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates . folder

Comment: @Jayreis I updated my answer, I tested it's worked for me. Good luck!